# Next.js, TypeScript and tsconfig.json 'jsx' property being overwritten

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tsconfig

How to stop the `jsx` property being overwritten from 'react' to 'preserve' by NextJS when running the development server?

My `tsconfig.json` file:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

AFAIK the jsx option must be `react` to compile my `tsx` files to `jsx`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answered here:

https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/937

Essentially you extend the current `tsconfig.json` with one specifically for jest and then reference that `tsconfig.json` from your `jest.config.js`.

Comment: For anyone wondering how to extend their current tsconfig.json: `tsconfig.test.json { "extends": "./tsconfig.json", "compilerOptions": { "jsx": "react" } }`